# selichos on yom kippur

Tags: yom-kippur, nuschaot, selichot

Yom kippur is a day of kapparah (forgiveness). In most machzorim it says at a certain point in every t'filla 'Now one says selichot'. Does any shul ever say them? Which?

Comment: You mean, do they insert certain poems followed by _el melech_ and the 13 attributes of mercy in the middle of the different repetitions of the amida? I believe they do that at Yeshiva University per the instruction of RYDS.

Comment: @Double AA I do.

Comment: Breuer's says them, as do schuls affiliated with Machon Moreshes Ashkenaz.

Answer (score 1):

The GGBH say selichos in each tefillah on Yom Kippur.

Answer (score 1):

Beth Aaron in Teaneck says them (they hand out a booklet).